# MD5 and SHA-2 collisions in Python

Tags: python, hash, mp3, md5, sha

I'm writing a simple MP3 cataloguer to keep track of which MP3's are on my various devices. I was planning on using MD5 or SHA2 keys to identify matching files even if they have been renamed/moved, etc. I'm not trying to match MP3's that are logically equivalent (i.e.: same song but encoded differently). I have about 8000 MP3's. Only about 6700 of them generated unique keys.

My problem is that I'm running into collisions regardless of the hashing algorithm I choose. In one case, I have two files that happen to be tracks #1 and #2 on the same album, they are different file sizes yet produce identical hash keys whether I use MD5, SHA2-256, SHA2-512, etc...

This is the first time I'm really using hash keys on files and this is an unexpected result. I feel something fishy is going on here from the little I know about these hashing algorithms. Could this be an issue related to MP3's or Python's implementation?

Here's the snippet of code that I'm using:

```
    data = open(path, 'r').read()

    m = hashlib.md5(data)

    m.update(data)

    md5String = m.hexdigest()
```

Any answers or insights to why this is happening would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**--UPDATE--**:

I tried executing this code in linux (with Python 2.6) and it did not produce a collision. As demonstrated by the stat call, the files are not the same. I also downloaded WinMD5 and this did not produce a collision(8d327ef3937437e0e5abbf6485c24bb3 and 9b2c66781cbe8c1be7d6a1447994430c). Is this a bug with Python hashlib on Windows? I tried the same under Python 2.7.1 and 2.6.6 and both provide the same result.

```
import hashlib
import os

def createMD5( path):

    fh = open(path, 'r')
    data = fh.read()
    m = hashlib.md5(data)
    md5String = m.hexdigest()
    fh.close()
    return md5String

print os.stat(path1)
print os.stat(path2)
print createMD5(path1)
print createMD5(path2)

>>> nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=6617216L, st_atime=1303808346L, st_mtime=1167098073L, st_ctime=1290222341L)
>>> nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=4921346L, st_atime=1303808348L, st_mtime=1167098076L, st_ctime=1290222341L)   
>>> a7a10146b241cddff031eb03bd572d96
>>> a7a10146b241cddff031eb03bd572d96
```

Comment: Are you sure that the MP3 files are actually different themselves? Hashing collisions are fairly unlikely, especially with larger, more advanced algorithms such as SHA-1 and SHA-2. Having that many collisions may just suggest that you actually have many duplicate files.

Comment: BTW, why do you call m.update()? m=hashlib.md5("foo"); m.update("foo") is equivalent to m=hashlib.md5("foofoo").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I sort of have the feeling that you are reading a chunk of data which is smaller than the expected, and this chunk happens to be the same for both files. I don't know why, but try to open the file in binary with 'rb'. read() should read up to end of file, but windows behaves differently. From the docs

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode
>   opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb',
>   and 'r+b'. Python on Windows makes a
>   distinction between text and binary
>   files; the end-of-line characters in
>   text files are automatically altered
>   slightly when data is read or written.
>   This behind-the-scenes modification to
>   file data is fine for ASCII text
>   files, but it’ll corrupt binary data
>   like that in JPEG or EXE files. Be
>   very careful to use binary mode when
>   reading and writing such files. On
>   Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b'
>   to the mode, so you can use it
>   platform-independently for all binary
>   files.

Comment: thanks replacing open(path, 'r') with open(path, 'rb') did the trick. I now get two distinct keys

Answer (score 2):

The files you're having a problem with are almost certainly identical if several different hashing algorithms all return the same hash results on them, or there's a bug in your implementation.

As a sanity test write your own "hash" that just returns the file's contents wholly, and see if this one generates the same "hashes".

Comment: Please see my updated post. The files are definitely not identical.

Comment: @Jesse: interesting. I suggest you open a Python bug (http://bugs.python.org/) describing the problem - what's important here is the 2 files for which on windows you get different hashes and on linux the same hashes

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, a single hash collision is unlikely, and multiple nigh on impossible, unless the files are identical. I would recommend generating the sums with an external utility as something of a sanity check. For example, in Ubuntu (and most/all other Linux distributions):

```
blair@blair-eeepc:~$ md5sum Bandwagon.mp3
b87cbc2c17cd46789cb3a3c51a350557  Bandwagon.mp3
blair@blair-eeepc:~$ sha256sum Bandwagon.mp3 
b909b027271b4c3a918ec19fc85602233a4c5f418e8456648c426403526e7bc0  Bandwagon.mp3
```

A quick Google search shows there are similar utilities available for Windows machines. If you see the collisions with the external utilities, then the files are identical. If there are no collisions, you are doing something wrong. I doubt the Python implementation is wrong, as I get the same results when doing the hash in Python:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5(open('Bandwagon.mp3', 'r').read()).hexdigest()
'b87cbc2c17cd46789cb3a3c51a350557'
>>> hashlib.sha256(open('Bandwagon.mp3', 'r').read()).hexdigest()
'b909b027271b4c3a918ec19fc85602233a4c5f418e8456648c426403526e7bc0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Delan Azabani said, there is something fishy here; collisions are bound to happen, but not that often. Check if the songs are the same, and update your post please.

Also, if you feel  that you don't have enough keys, you can use two (or even more) hashing algorithms at the same time: by using MD5 for example, you have `2**128`, or `340282366920938463463374607431768211456` keys. By using SHA-1, you have `2**160` or `1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976` keys. By combining them, you have `2**128 * 2**160`, or `497323236409786642155382248146820840100456150797347717440463976893159497012533375533056`.

(But if you ask me, MD5 is more than enough for your needs.)